# How can I iterate through nested arrays?

Tags: perl, arrays, loops

I have created an array as follows

```
while (defined ($line = `<STDIN>`))

        {
        chomp ($line);
        push @stack,($line);
        }
```

each line has two numbers.

```
15 6
2  8
```

how do iterate over each item in each line?

i.e. I want to print

```
15
6
2
8
```

I understand it's something like

```
foreach (@{stack}) (@stack){

    print "?????
}
```

This is where I am stuck.

Comment: Don't understand how what you want to print is different from what you've got. Also, those backticks don't look right.

Comment: Ditto on the backtics. Remove them and use `while (my $line = <>)`.

Comment: `while(my $line=<>)` gets automatically converted to `while(defined(my $line=<>))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) documentation. That's the Perl Data Structures Cookbook, which has examples for dealing with arrays of arrays. From what you're doing though, it doesn't look like you need an array of arrays.

For your problem of taking two numbers per line and outputting one number per line, just turn the whitespace into newlines:

```
 while( <> ) {
     s/\s+/\n/; # turn all whitespace runs into newlines
     print;     # it's ready to print
     }
```

With Perl 5.10, you can use the new `\h` character class that matches only horizontal whitespace:

```
 while( <> ) {
     s/\h+/\n/; # turn all horizontal whitespace runs into newlines
     print;     # it's ready to print
     }
```

As a Perl one-liner, that's just:

```
 % perl -pe 's/\h+/\n/' file.txt
```

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while ( my $data = <DATA> ) {
    my @values = split ' ', $data;
    print $_, "\n" for @values;
}


__DATA__
15 6
2  8
```

Output:

```
C:\Temp> h
15
6
2
8
```

Alternatively, if you want to store each line in `@stack` and print out later:

```
my @stack = map { [ split ] } grep { chomp; length } <DATA>;
```

The line above slurps everything coming from the `DATA` filehandle into a list of lines (because `<DATA>` happens in list context). The `grep` chomps each line and filters by length after chomping (to avoid getting any trailing empty lines in the data file -- you can avoid it if there are none). The `map` then splits each line along spaces, and then creates an anonymous array reference for each line. Finally, such array references are stored in each element of `@stack`. You might want to use `Data::Dumper` to look at `@stack` to understand what's going on.

```
print join("\n", @$_), "\n" for @stack;
```

Now, we look over each entry in stack, dereferencing each array in turn, then joining the elements of each array with newlines to print one element per line.

Output:

```
C:\Temp> h
15
6
2
8
```

The long way of writing essentially the same thing (with less memory consumption) would be:

```
my @stack;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    last unless $line =~ /\S/;
    my @values = split ' ', $line;
    push @stack, \@values;
}

for my $ref ( @stack ) {
    print join("\n", @$ref), "\n";
}
```

Finally, if you wanted do something other than printing all values, say, sum all the numbers, you should store one value per element of `@stack`:

```
use List::Util qw( sum );

my @stack;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    last unless $line =~ /\S/;
    my @values = split ' ', $line;
    push @stack, @values;
}

printf "The sum is %d\n", sum @stack;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while ($line = <STDIN>) {
    chomp ($line);
    push @stack, $line;
}

# prints each line
foreach $line (@stack) {
    print "$line\n";
}

# splits each line into items using ' ' as separator
# and prints the items
foreach $line (@stack) {
    @items = split / /, $line;

    foreach $item (@items) {
        print $item . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the final 'for' need to be 'foreach' also?

Comment: Foreach would have been more easy to understand for sure, from perldoc perlsyn:
> The "foreach" keyword is actually a synonym for the "for" keyword, so you can use "foreach" for readability or "for" for brevity.

Comment: `foreach` and `for` behave identically. Many perlers prefer to use `for` exclusively.

Comment: I used to be a big fan of foreach.  Now I have forgotten that it even exists.  (Or maybe I've just "for" that it even exists...)

Comment: Well, when you use that much code, saving four characters is sorta like taking a cup of water out of the ocean :)

Comment: If you want all the lines in an array, just use --> my @lines = <STDIN> . When you want to print them all, it's just ---> print @lines . That way you don't have to argue about for versus foreach.

Comment: perl -pe 's/\s+/\n/g' can do the job but I think the point to the OP is not to get ready to go code but to understand how to do it..

Comment: How to do what? You're code is just what I did, with just a lot more work. No one has even shown a single reference in any code yet.

Answer (score 0):

I use 'for' for "C" style loops, and 'foreach' for iterating over lists.

Comment: There is no need to make such an artificial distinction between the two.

Comment: There is no need, but that's what I do too. It's just syntactic sugar.

Comment: I use `for` for both. C style loops will be written with `loop` in Perl6, and `foreach` will get renamed to `for`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
open IN, "< read.txt" or
    die "Can't read in 'read.txt'!";

my $content = join '', <IN>;

while ($content =~ m`(\d+)`g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```