# How do I access and print a 3 or 4 dimensional hash in Perl?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I iterate through nested arrays in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571501/how-can-i-iterate-through-nested-arrays-in-perl)

I am trying to create a 3 - 4 dimensional hash by

```
for ( $j=0;$j<$#temp_1;$j++)
{
   for ( $i=0;$i<$#temp_2;$i++)
   {
      $var1{$mode}{$temp_1[$j]}{$temp_2[$i]}=$temp_3[$i];
   }
}
```

`$mode` is predefined. also arrays `@temp_1` , `@temp_2` and `@temp3`
If I want to print the values, what do I do?

Comment: Please specify expected output - instead of the blank "print the values."

Comment: In this case you need the indices because you have to index into @temp3, so the for() loop is appropriate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to print the whole shebang after the end of the loop, you mean?

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper(\%var1);
```